# SDK Twilio Android crashes with highers version Android

Tags: android, sdk, twilio

When I use the version  **5.0.1 and 5.1.1  of Android**, the **SDK Twilio** crashes with this error :

> JNI Detector.

I seek the solution to solve this error.

If someone has an idea, I am interested

Comment: Which SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Malcolm, I'm Megan from Twilio. At the time of this writing, we have a known bug regarding this issue in version 1.2.8 of the Android SDK though it's due to be fixed very soon.

In the meantime, it's suggested to rollback to 1.2.7.

Keep an eye out on the [changelog](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android/changelog) for the fix.

Hope this helps.